Python interpreter error in anaconda
I have landed in the following problem after changing the directory of Anaconda installed in ubuntu 20.04.
 user@user:~$ conda activate
 -bash: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda: /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Could you please help me with this?
